# How to remove height and width?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

currently I am working on an image slider with jquery. I have downloaded the code from the net. My code demo is [here](http://codecanyon.net/item/boutique-carousel/full_screen_preview/113093?ref=NetPremium&clickthrough_id=17202776&redirect_back=true).

My question is: how can I remove the height and width attaching dynamically to image tag as inline style?

Thanks.

Comment: what do you expect the high and width to be after it's removed? 0 ?

Comment: i expect that if i remove height and width then it must take original  height and width and not the one that the code assign to them..

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try to use this code:

```
$('your-image').css({ 
  width: '',
  height: ''
});
```

If you want to set the "original" image dimensions try this:

```
$('your-image').css({ 
  width: 'auto',
  height: 'auto'
});
```

Comment: What browser? I checked in FF and Chrome and inline style attributes was removed just like you want. If you want to set "original" size try to use 'auto' instead of ''.

Comment: yaa u r right but when i click on next image the size again switch to its predefined value .How to resolve that?

Comment: Where can i see this behaviour? "Predefined" it is "Not original, but set through inline style"?

Comment: yaa u r right now i got my ans  i removed height and width  in boutique_min.js    #boutique .front img{margin:6px;width:280px;height:400px}    and now got my original image with their original height and width. But the layout is totally changed man hw can i solve that one.

Comment: I can solve this without seeing all the picture. Give a link to your page where the demo is (with your fixes for width/height)

Comment: yaa i know buddy u can but actually my code is on localhost and i am unable to show u that one . ok can u do 1 thing give me ur gmail id i can show u screen shots of my problems....

Answer (score 12):

To make it work from all ways, you need to remove both attribute and css.
This is work on my code.

```
$('your-image')
   .removeAttr("width").removeAttr("height")
   .css({ width: "", height: "" });
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a VERY simple solution with jQuery. I found the answer at wpwizard.net.

Here's the URL: http://wpwizard.net/jquery/remove-img-height-and-width-with-jquery/

Here's the jQuery:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    $('img').each(function(){ 
        $(this).removeAttr('width')
        $(this).removeAttr('height');
    });

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with vanilla JavaScript too.

```
let articleContentImages = document.getElementById("articleContent").getElementsByTagName("img");
for(let i = 0; i < articleContentImages.length; i++){
    articleContentImages[i].style.height = "auto";
    articleContentImages[i].style.width = "auto";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('img').width('auto').height('auto');
```

Answer (score 0):

inherit could be one of the way.

```js
$('your-image').css({ width: "inherit", height: "inherit" });
```